# Not able to generate the correct graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have been trying to generate a heatmap in python such that the Matplotlib graph that is generated does not have any white margins in both x and y axes and the graph's scaling must be 1:1 with respect to the x and y axes units. I have tried many things but the best I have been able to achieve so far is able to remove the x axis white margins but not the y one. Here's an example:
This is what I am getting:
[image: This is what I am getting]
This is what I want:
[image: This is what I want]

Here's the code through which I am generating the graph:

```
plt.style.use('classic')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.pcolormesh(x_mesh,y_mesh,intensity)
plt.plot(x,y,linestyle="None",marker='.',markerfacecolor='white')
#plt.colorbar()
#plt.axis('off')
plt.margins(x=0,y=0)
plt.ylim([0,254])
plt.xlim([0,538])
plt.savefig('plottest.png', dpi=144, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.show()
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @medium-dimensional Okay did that but still getting the exact same result :(

Comment: @medium-dimensional No doing that removes the margins but makes the aspect ratio of the heatmap change, as I mentioned earlier I want both x and y units to be 1:1 and have no x and y margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `plt.axis('equal')` to `plt.axis('scaled')`. As the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html) says:

> equal: ... Explicit data limits may not be respected in this case.